# Remove everything until the first occurrence of a bracket "(" in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset with council and shire names that look somewhat like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
example <- data.frame(LGA_formal = c("Moira (S)","Monash (C)","Moonee Valley (C)",             
                        "Moorabool (S)","Moreland (C)" ,"Mornington Peninsula (S)"), 
                        Median_age = c(34,34,56,78,88,99))
```

I would like to create a new column that is just the names, but want to keep the old column, so that it looks like this:

```
example_desired <- data.frame(LGA_formal =c("Moira (S)","Monash (C)","Moonee Valley (C)",             
                        "Moorabool (S)","Moreland (C)" ,"Mornington Peninsula (S)"), 
                        Median_age = c(34,34,56,78,88,99),
LGA = c("Moira","Monash","Moonee Valley",             
                        "Moorabool","Moreland","Mornington Peninsula"))
```

I have been trying to remove everything up to the first bracket like this but am getting an error

```
example_desired <- example %>%
  mutate(LGA = str_extract(LGA_formal, ".+?(?=))")) %>%
mutate(LGA = trimws(LGA))
```

However this is not working and I am getting the following error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `LGA`.
x Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN, context=`.+?(?=))`)
i Input `LGA` is `str_extract(LGA_formal, ".+?(?=))")`.
```

How can I specify everything up to a bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sub` with  `*\\(.*` to remove everything after the first `(` and also spaces before.

```
example$LGA <- sub(" *\\(.*", "", example$LGA_formal)
identical(example, example_desired) #test if desired is reached
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

In `stringr` you may do something like this

```
example %>% mutate(LGA = str_remove_all(LGA_formal, ' \\(.*'))
                LGA_formal Median_age                  LGA
1                Moira (S)         34                Moira
2               Monash (C)         34               Monash
3        Moonee Valley (C)         56        Moonee Valley
4            Moorabool (S)         78            Moorabool
5             Moreland (C)         88             Moreland
6 Mornington Peninsula (S)         99 Mornington Peninsula
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to extract what you need :

```
transform(example, LGA = sub('(.*)\\s\\(.*', '\\1', LGA_formal))

#                LGA_formal Median_age                  LGA
#1                Moira (S)         34                Moira
#2               Monash (C)         34               Monash
#3        Moonee Valley (C)         56        Moonee Valley
#4            Moorabool (S)         78            Moorabool
#5             Moreland (C)         88             Moreland
#6 Mornington Peninsula (S)         99 Mornington Peninsula
```

Or in `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

example %>% mutate(LGA = str_extract(LGA_formal, '.*(?=\\s\\()'))
```